# How to translate intrinsics to a legacy architecture?

Tags: clang, llvm, intrinsics, llvm-clang, klee

I want to run [klee](http://klee.github.io/) on a performance optimized code, that uses various instruction set extensions, like sse2, sse4.1. Unfortunately llvm-3.4 interpreter does not support them:

```
LLVM ERROR: Code generator does not support intrinsic function 'llvm.x86.sse41.ptestz'!
```

I can not just disable it on compilation, because, they are explicitly used in source code. I think, what I need is a kind of automatic backward translation of such instruction into a vanilla x86. Does Clang support such feature?

Comment: that'll be possible, but the output will run very slowly